# Did Herman Melville write the "textbook" chapters of Moby Dick?

Tags: literature

In *Moby Dick* there is a long chapter that is meant to be an excerpt from a textbook on whales. Did Melville compose that or was it actually copied from a textbook on whales?

Comment: I do not believe this question is at all on-topic for this site. I've tried to think of other sites that we could recommend migrating it to, but it is off-topic for Writer's. If anyone has other suggestions let me know.

Comment: @StevenDrennon: How about Biology, with regard to the "cetological" reference? The question (as re-written) would be, "Would a layman know this stuff, or would he need to get it from an expert

Comment: @twosheds:Fair enough.

Comment: people have been editing my question to make it be off topic. I don'c care whether Melville was able to write it (a speculative social science question), I only care whether he did actually write it ( a history question)

Comment: This is a history question. Reopen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Cetology of Moby Dick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cetology_of_Moby-Dick) was written by [Herman Melville](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herman_Melville), but it draws upon the works of several naturalists and anatomists of his time, including:

- [Thomas Beale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Beale), who wrote [*The Natural History of the Sperm Whale*](https://archive.org/details/naturalhistorys00bealgoog)
- [Frederick Debell Bennett](http://species.wikimedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Debell_Bennett), who wrote the [*Narrative of a Whaling Voyage Round the Globe*](https://archive.org/details/narrativeofwhali02bennrich)

Both were surgeons on whaling ships, and wrote of the anatomy of whales. They, and Melville as well, further relied upon the writings of the great naturalist [John Hunter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Hunter_%28surgeon%29), especially his [*Observations on the Structure and Oeconomy of Whales*](https://archive.org/details/philtrans08928902).

Wikipedia has [an image of Melville's copy of Beale's book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x1dR.jpg):

[image]